# Não consigo gerar o Histograma Animado pelo notebook do matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histograma, jupyter-notebook

Oi, não estou conseguindo obter o resultado final do notebook do matplotlib (estou tentando pelo colab), que seria um histograma animado:
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/animation/animated_histogram.html

Acontece o seguinte erro:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py", line 196, in process
func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 951, in _start
self._init_draw()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1743, in _init_draw
self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1766, in _draw_frame
self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
File "", line 7, in animate
for count, rect in zip(n, bar_container.patches):
AttributeError: 'silent_list' object has no attribute 'patches'

Comment: Tu poderias fornecer maiores informações, para nos ajudar a tentar reproduzir o erro localmente e, então, poder te ajudar a encontrar a solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há dois problemas em rodar o notebook que você mencionou no Google Colab:

- A versão do matplotlib instalada no Colab.
- O backend do matplotlib no Colab, que por padrão é inline.

A solução para esses problemas seria:

- Atualizar a versão do matplotlib para >= 3.4: `!pip install matplotlib>=3.4.0`.
- Utilizar o backend de widget: `%matplotlib widget`. Isso requer a instalação da biblioteca ipympl: `!pip install ipympl`.

Além disso, devido a uma particularidade do Google Colab, é necessário rodar as seguintes linhas de código para habilitar o `ipympl`:

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
```

Feito isso, tudo deve funcionar. Segue o código completo do notebook: https://gist.github.com/giovaniceotto/6820dcc4181608dbbe25a85339deb7e9